Как переносить курсор на строку вверх на python
Пример:
Через функцию print("Текст, который не трогаем\nhello\nworld") выводится в консоль 3 строки:

Текст, который не трогаем
hello
world

Нужно с командной строки стереть вторую и третью строчку и заменить их на другой текст. Будет выглядеть примерно так:

Текст, который не трогаем
Изменили текст№1
Изменили текст№2


Простой способ просто каждый раз заново полностью выводить весь текст только с измененными значениями, дополнительно можно очищать терминал через os.system("cls") или os.system("clear") в зависимости от вашей ОС

Для уточнения: Используется мобильное приложение "pydroid 3" на базе Linux (судя по platform.system()). Пробовал использовать print("text",end="\r"),но это не подходит для данного случая. Курсор возвращается только в начало строки,но не переходит на другую. Использовать полное очищение консоли не хочется,веть я проверяю на наличие ошибок при долгой работе скрипта

Могу предложить использовать ANSI escape-коды
:
import os
os.system('')  # вкл ANSI escape-кодов для win

print("Текст, который не трогаем\nhello\nworld")
print("\033[2;1H\033[J", end="")  
print("Изменили текст№1\nИзменили текст№2")



print("Логи\n"*5)
print("Текст, который не трогаем\nhello\nworld")

print("\033[2A\033[J", end="")

print("Изменили текст№1\nИзменили текст№2")



Вот, если я правильно понял задание, исходя из заголовка, поскольку далее речь идёт уже о заменах, а не о позиции курсора. Готовый скрипт, демонстрирующий работу с позицией курсора:
import os
import ctypes

def lib_set_console_position(x=0, y=0):

 class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

 ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), COORD(x, y))

# Пример использования
lib_set_console_position(10, 5)

os.system("pause")

